# How to display “NO COUNTRY FOUND” input search in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to display text that matches user input. It worked, but there was a problem that made me want to pop up a notification "NO COUNTRY FOUND". If I enter a word on the input "AFGHANISTON" or "ALGEZIA" or other. Then i want this code will operate `$("ul.suggestions").html('NO COUNTRY FOUND')`.

So, how to make display "NO COUNTRY FOUND" notification, if the inserted word does not match? Because if I am wrong in entering a word on that input, it only displays a void

```js
var selectValues = {
    "af": "AFGHANISTAN",
    "al": "ALBANIA",
    "dz": "ALGERIA"
};
$(document).on('click keyup', '.country-tager', function(e) {
    var tagValue = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    if (tagValue.length > 0) {
        $("ul.suggestions").html('');
        $.each(selectValues, function(key, index) {
            if (this.indexOf(tagValue) > -1) {
                $("ul.suggestions").append('<li><a data="' + key + '">' + this + '</a></li>');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("ul.suggestions").html('please insert');
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="country-tager country-search-input typeahead tag-field" autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Search country">
<ul class="country-list suggestions"></ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the matching has completed successfully, you can count the number of `li`s in the list, and if they are zero, you can set the HTML to `NO COUNTRY FOUND`.

Following is a working demo:

```js
var selectValues = {
    "af": "AFGHANISTAN",
    "al": "ALBANIA",
    "dz": "ALGERIA"
};
$(document).on('click keyup', '.country-tager', function(e) {
    var tagValue = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    if (tagValue.length > 0) {
        $("ul.suggestions").html('');
        $.each(selectValues, function(key, index) {
            if (this.indexOf(tagValue) > -1) {
                $("ul.suggestions").append('<li><a data="' + key + '">' + this + '</a></li>');
            }
        });
        
        if ($('ul.suggestions li').length === 0) {
          $("ul.suggestions").html('NO COUNTRY FOUND');
        }
    } else {
        $("ul.suggestions").html('please insert');
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="country-tager country-search-input typeahead tag-field" autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Search country">
<ul class="country-list suggestions"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a `count` variable and assign to `0`;

Now, **if you find any text when input is typed**, increment the `count variable`

Then check the condition,

```
 if(count == 0){
     $("ul.suggestions").html('No Country found');
 }
```

```js
var selectValues = {
    "af": "AFGHANISTAN",
    "al": "ALBANIA",
    "dz": "ALGERIA"
};
$(document).on('click keyup', '.country-tager', function(e) {
    var tagValue = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    var count = 0;
    if (tagValue.length > 0) {
        $("ul.suggestions").html('');
        $.each(selectValues, function(key, index) {
            if (this.indexOf(tagValue) > -1) {
                count  = count + 1;
                $("ul.suggestions").append('<li><a data="' + key + '">' + this + '</a></li>');
            }
        });
        if(count == 0){
        $("ul.suggestions").html('No Country found');
        }
    } else {
        $("ul.suggestions").html('please insert');
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="country-tager country-search-input typeahead tag-field" autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Search country">
<ul class="country-list suggestions"></ul>
```

[**Here is a Working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/UfJz0cPm1pOH7sO16Frv?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If the $("ul.suggestions").html() is empty after iterating through all country names, then you can populate the 'No Country Found' html as shown in the below code.

```js
var selectValues = {
    "af": "AFGHANISTAN",
    "al": "ALBANIA",
    "dz": "ALGERIA"
};
$(document).on('onclick keyup', '.country-tager', function(e) {
    var tagValue = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    if (tagValue.length > 0) {
        $("ul.suggestions").html('');
        $.each(selectValues, function(key, index) {
            if (this.indexOf(tagValue) > -1) {
                $("ul.suggestions").append('<li><a data="' + key + '">' + this + '</a></li>');
            }
  
        });
  if($("ul.suggestions").html()=='')
  {
   $("ul.suggestions").html('NO COUNTRY FOUND');
  }
    } else {
        $("ul.suggestions").html('please insert');
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="country-tager country-search-input typeahead tag-field" autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Search country">
<ul class="country-list suggestions"></ul>
```